# how to get callback of sending mail in android

Tags: android, email, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm developing an android application that requires to send normal email. I'm using following code.

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"some text here");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share us via Email"));
```

Now my question is, is there a way to obtain a callback when user sents mail successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use startActivityForResult() method

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

`ACTION_SEND` does not send email. `ACTION_SEND` lets the user share content of a specified MIME type. Whether the user chooses to send via email, who they send the email to, whether they change the content, whether they send the email at all, and so forth is up to the user, and your app is not informed of any of this.